# Automation of documenting code base using Doxygen plug in Jenkins CI environment

Tags: jenkins, doxygen, jenkins-plugins

I use a shell script to  create/run  doxygen doxyfile to document my code base

which  works absolutely fine(Schedule runs and recursive scan code base also

works fine).

Now my requirement is to do the same job using Jenkins CI.

I added doxygen plug which generates documentation output and stores the result in Jenkin workspace.

My question, is there any another ways to run script and generate doxyfile in 
Jenkins environment and also

How to create url link to display doxygen HTML output.

Comment: You can specify a shell script to run as a build step.

Comment: I  pushed my shell script via SCM to Jenkins workspace,While  run those shell scriptr  in build step i am getting permission denied error .
I changed the permission of the below folder to +777 R var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test/workspace
also changed the permission of my script file in the above folder but could not resolve permission error.
Tried sudo, su before shell script also does not worked.

Comment: while enter  entire script in the build step and run  the job i am getting below error:                                                                      "java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bin/sh" (in directory 

"/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test/workspace"): error=2, No such file or directory"

Comment: By any chance, could there be missing a slash? *#!/bin/bash*

Comment: No that is not the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen the Jenkins [DocLink plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/DocLinks+Plugin)? This plugin makes it easy to put a link on your project page to documentation generated in a build.